# Javascript setting date not working ok Chrome

Tags: javascript

Here's an issue I'm getting setting a date with Javascript on Chrome

```
"17-09-2019"
var [day, month, year] = date.split('-');
undefined
day
"17"
month
"09"
year
"2019"
var set_date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), parseInt(day));
undefined
console.log(set_date);
VM5577:1 Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)
undefined
```

So I have a date `17-09-2019` and point here is `09` is `September` but when I set the date I get back `October`.
Been scratching my head over this one for a while now. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Months are zero-based. You need to subtract one from the month.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ok now it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The months in javascript starts from 0. You just need to subtract 1 to your `parseInt(month)`:

```js
var date = "17-09-2019";
var [day, month, year] = date.split('-');
console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year}`)
var set_date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1, parseInt(day));
console.log(set_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set out this , month starting from index `0`

```
var date = "17-09-2019"
var [day, month, year] = date.split('-');
month = month - 1;
var set_date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), parseInt(day));

console.log(set_date); //Tue Sep 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```